# Should the micro controller be the peripheral or the central?

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I recently purchased a Bluetooth 4.0 LE micro controller known as the Bluno.  It's an Arduino compatible micro controller that has BT4.0LE built-in with no need for additional hardware.  Anyways, I can program the micro controller to act as a central or a peripheral and same goes for the iPod Touch 5G that I plan on using to communicate with the device.

I initially thought that I should make the Bluno act the central and have the iPod Touch act the peripheral because the app I have written in Obj-c sends messages to a micro controller, and previously the micro controller we exhibit a behavior based on the message it would receive.

However when I look at the sample app written by the people who sell the Bluno they have the iDevice configured as the central, which makes me wonder because their app has the micro controller responding to what the user inputs into the app and then have the micro controller perform an action.

Needless to say I'm a little confused, any constructive thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles of the phone and the microcontroller really depend on what you're creating.

In the majority of cases though, the microcontroller has some sensors attached to it and that data is made available over bluetooth, and that is your "peripheral". Your phone app in the "central" role will read that data and likely have some user interaction based on that data.

This Apple doc explains it well: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

> In Bluetooth low energy communication, there are two key players: the
>   central and the peripheral. Each player has a different role to play
>   in Bluetooth low energy communication. A peripheral typically has data
>   that is needed by other devices. A central typically uses the
>   information served up by a peripheral to accomplish some task. For
>   example, a digital thermostat equipped with Bluetooth low energy
>   technology might provide the temperature of a room to an iOS app that
>   then displays the temperature in a user-friendly way.